# Use a variable in another function

Tags: python, pygame

So part of this function, I have two variables, `color` and `color_rect`, Is it possible to use these variables another function later on. I tried putting global before it, however it resulted in either a syntax error or say `variable` is used prior to global declaration

Full code:

```
def colors():
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
button_1.centerx = width/2
colors = [("White", (255, 255, 255)), ("Red", (255, 0, 0)), ("Green", (0, 255, 0)), ("Blue", (0, 0, 255))]
current_color = 0
color_t, color = colors[current_color]

colors_rect = [("White", (255, 255, 255)), ("Red", (255, 0, 0)), ("Green", (0, 255, 0)), ("Blue", (0, 0, 255))]
current_color_rect = 0
color_t_rect, color_rect = colors[current_color]

text_particle = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, 'Particle:', (255,255,255), 100, 300, False)
text_colors = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 50, 'Colors', (255,255,255), button_1.centerx, button_1.centery, False)
text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)
ball = pygame.Rect(350,200,50,50)
text_rect = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, 'Ball:', (255,255,255), 310, 300, False)
text_color_rect = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t_rect, color_rect, 390, 300, False)

particles = []
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (135, 206, 235), button_1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color_rect, ball, 3)
    screen.blit(*text_rect)
    screen.blit(*text_particle)
    screen.blit(*text_colors)
    screen.blit(*text_color)
    screen.blit(*text_color_rect)
    textRect = text_color[1]
    textRect_rect = text_color_rect[1]

    particles.append([[150,200],[random.randint(0,20) / 10 - 1, 1], random.randint(4,6)])
    for particle in particles:
        particle[0][0] += particle[1][0]
        particle[0][1] += particle[1][1]
        particle[2] -= 0.1
        particle[1][1] += 0.03
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, [int(particle[0][0]), int(particle[0][1])], int(particle[2]))
        if particle[2] <= 0:
            particles.remove(particle)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and textRect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                current_color += 1
                if current_color >= len(colors):
                    current_color = 0
                color_t, color = colors[current_color]
                text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)

            if event.button == 1 and textRect_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                current_color_rect += 1
                if current_color_rect >= len(colors_rect):
                    current_color_rect = 0
                color_t_rect, color_rect = colors_rect[current_color_rect]
                text_color_rect = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t_rect, color_rect, 390, 300, False)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

**The two variables are `color` and `color_rect`. Note I said the variable `color` and not `colors`.**

Answer (score 0):

Move your variables outside/above the `def`. That changes their scope so they can be used across all the functions in your same `.py` code file.

```
color = ()

def method_that_uses_color():
    do_something(color)

def colors():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
    button_1.centerx = width/2
    colors = [("White", (255, 255, 255)), ("Red", (255, 0, 0)), ("Green", (0, 255, 0)), ("Blue", (0, 0, 255))]
    current_color = 0
    color_t, color = colors[current_color]
    [.......]
```

I wouldn't do it like this though if you can help it. Better practice to pass the dependencies in as method parameters, and return the uniquely calculated outputs as function results.

```
def __init__():
    color = colors()
    do_something(color)

def method_that_uses_color(color):
    do_something(color)

def colors():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
    button_1.centerx = width/2
    colors = [("White", (255, 255, 255)), ("Red", (255, 0, 0)), ("Green", (0, 255, 0)), ("Blue", (0, 0, 255))]
    current_color = 0
    color_t, color = colors[current_color]
    [.......]
    return color
```

Comment: If I try adding `color_rect_box_pygame = ()` before the function, and try saying `color_rect_box_pygame += color` it says `color_rect_box_pygame += color
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'color_rect_box_pygame' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and cleanest way, I think) would be to make this function a class method and store those variables as member variables, i.e. `self.color` and `self.color_rect`. Then, as long as you use the same instance of the class, those variables will be the same across all functions of that class.

You can learn more about Python classes [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-python-classes/).